# How can I override the default string formatter in python?

Tags: python, string, formatting

Is there some way I can change the `Formatter` python's `string.format()` uses? I have a custom one (disables the `check_unused_args` method), but this requires me use the `formatter.format("text")` syntax,  instead of the `"text".format()` syntax, which I'd prefer.

Can I swap out the 'default formatter' somehow?

NOTE: This is just a small project, I don't need to worry about messing up libraries or anything.

Comment: You can derive your own string class from the built-in one and provide your own `format` method.

Comment: See also: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there some way I can change the Formatter python's string.format() uses?

No.  I think the rational is because it would lead to really confusing code.  People would expect `format_string.format(...)` to behave one way, and it would behave differently causing bugs and general sadness.

---

You *can* however, explicitly tell python that you want to use a different formatter.

```
class MyFormatter(string.Formatter):
    """This is my formatter which is better than the standard one."""
    # customization here ...

MyFormatter().format(format_string, *args, **kwargs)
```

By inheriting from `string.Formatter`, you gain access to the entire `Formatter` API which can make your custom formatter work better.

If that weren't enough, you can customize how objects format themselves using the `__format__` hook method which `Formatter` objects call (including the standard one).

Comment: Aww, too bad. I see the reasoning though. This is the solution I've been using.

Comment: Unlike other languages (e.g. Ruby), Python generally doesn't let you modify builtin types (e.g. string).  I personally think this is a good thing -- it forces you to be explicit.  But, of course others might disagree.  :-)

Comment: I think you can just replace `str.format = MyFormatter().format` to change the default formatted to your implementation.